# Reusing the name of a custom RESTful route in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do something that I imagine looks like this:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get  'login', :action => 'login_form'
    post 'login', :action => 'login'
    get 'logout'
  end
end
```

I.e. I want two controller actions to bind to the same path with different methods. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the guide about routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
resources :users do
    collection do
        match  'login' => "users#login_form", via: :get
        post   'login'
        get 'logout'
    end
end
```

A `login_form` action does not sound very restful. Just saying ;)

Comment: You'll need to specify get on that first match, or it will match both get and post, and you'll never hit your second route.

Comment: How do I make it more restful then? :)

Comment: @railsdog: oh, I thought the default for match was `get`, and not both `get` and `post`...

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: well, it depends on what you want to do exactly. But you could make a sessions_controller, and the users#login_form action would be sessions#new action (like devise does).

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for the tip!